# Connect dataGridView to SQL query

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datagridview

I'm building a simple booking system with C# Windows Forms and SQL database. As a part of the program, user can add some text to textBoxes and click 'Search' button to search bookings that fill the search criterion. **When user clicks the button, SQL query is executed and query results are updated into dataGridView.**

Example below is simple example from my code. Format for `booking_id` is int and a string for `firstname`. Program keeps throwing `System.InvalidCastException` and error is somehow related to line that is trying to insert `booking_id` into SQL string. I have searched some information about this error but I'm still unable to fix it. It must be something very simple I'm missing here - could someone provide some help? Thanks you in advance!

```
// User clicks 'Search' butto.
private void button_Search1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string commandText = "SELECT * FROM Booking " +
        "INNER JOIN Customer ON Booking.customer_id = Customer.customer_id" +
        "WHERE Booking.booking_date IS NOT NULL AND " +
        "Booking.booking_id_id LIKE '%' + @booking_id + '%' " +
        "Customer.customer.firstname LIKE '%' + @firstname + '%'";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;" + @"AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Booking.mdf; Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        //Create a SqlCommand instance
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);

        //Add the parameter
        //THESE LINES CAUSE PROBLEM!?
        command.Parameters.Add("@booking_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(textBox_BookindId);
        command.Parameters.Add("@firstname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = textBox_Firstname;

        // Open SQL connection and execute query.
        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dataAdapter.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: Read the entire exception message.  I bet it states something like: "Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox' to type 'System.IConvertible'."

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to force the `booking_id_id` column in `Datatable dt` to be a string so it goes into a textbox nicely, then `CAST` the booking id to be a string when its selected. Note that I've named the column to be `Booking ID` using 'as'

`string commandText = "SELECT Customer.customer_id, Booking.booking_date, CAST(Booking.booking_id_id) as NVARCHAR(10)) as 'Booking ID', Customer.customer.firstname FROM Booking " + "INNER JOIN Customer ON Booking.customer_id = Customer.customer_id" + "WHERE Booking.booking_date IS NOT NULL AND " + "Booking.booking_id_id LIKE '%' + @booking_id + '%' " + "Customer.customer.firstname LIKE '%' + @firstname + '%'";`